Issue when trying to install react native firebase in a corporate environment
when i try install react native firebase the build show me a output like this
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-firebase_app'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-firebase_app:classpath'.
      > Could not resolve gradle.plugin.io.invertase.gradle:react-native:1.5.
        Required by:
            project :react-native-firebase_app > io.invertase.gradle.build:io.invertase.gradle.build.gradle.plugin:1.5
         > Could not resolve gradle.plugin.io.invertase.gradle:react-native:1.5.
            > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/io/invertase/gradle/react-native/1.5/react-native-1.5.pom'.
               > Could not GET 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/io/invertase/gradle/react-native/1.5/react-native-1.5.pom'.
                  > Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
                     > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.`your text`

I am in a corporate environment and I have a proxy configured, I already have it configured in the global gradle.properties:
systemProp.gradle.internal.http.sslDisable=true
systemProp.gradle.internal.https.sslDisable=true

I still have the error, any suggestions I can apply so that the proxy does not verify the certificates or configure.
PS: I also already installed the certificates in the keystore
I tried to disable ssl verification with these commands in gradle.properties
systemProp.gradle.internal.http.sslDisable=true
systemProp.gradle.internal.https.sslDisable=true.

I also tried to install the certificates, tried to deactivate the proxy, tried to connect to an external network through the VPN and I still have the same error.
